# Real world example of complex foregin key references

Tags: database-theory, databases

Give a real world, normalized example where table T1 has primary key (A, B), T2 has primary key (B, C) and T3 has primary key (A, C) and table 4 has a primary key (A, B, C) where (A,B) is a foregin key on T1, (B, C) is a foregin key on T2, and (A, C) is a foregin key on T3?

The motivation is this form is allowed in a relational database, but I cannot think of a usage of it.

Comment: I don't understand the downvote. I added some motivation in my post

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example:
Assume a database that is maintained in a school.
Here, T1 is a course enrollment table, where the (roll_number, course_number) is a primary key. It says which student has enrolled in which course.

Then, T2 is a course_details table where the primary key is (course_number, instructor_code). This is because a course could be delivered by multiple instructors.

Next, T3 has a primary key (roll_number, instructor_code) signifying the instructors to which a student is reporting to through some course.

Now, I think you will be able to carry forward and conclude it logically.

All the best.

PS. - Thanks for the bounty. I am in deep need of it. Thanks.

Comment: This example doesn't seems to be normalized

Comment: It is. Have a closer look. Please accept it as the answer.